# Fatal error when func is called with scene kit and swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a little problem, after a download i want to launch a function but i have this fatal error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when my download is end i call a function telechargementOK()

```
func telechargementOK() {
    println("Telechargement ok")
    renduScene()
}

func renduScene() {
    println("Chargement de la vue 3D")

    let scnView2 = self.view3D as SCNView
    scnView2.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/MASTER.dae")
    scnView2.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    scnView2.allowsCameraControl = true


    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var documentsDirectoryURL = filemgr.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
    documentsDirectoryURL = documentsDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/Modules.scnassets/Module-01.dae")
    let module1Scene = SCNScene(URL: documentsDirectoryURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
    //println("\(module1Scene)")
    scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
    module1 = scnViewModule1.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true)
    //println("\(module1)")
    scnView2.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(module1!)

    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "sceneTapped:")
    scnView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}
```

When i take this code to viewDidLoad() all is ok...

Stoun

UPDATE :

this is my complete code :

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Gare et Connexions
//
//  Created by Stoun on 25/02/2016.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Stoun. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SceneKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var view3D : UIView?

let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

var scnView3 = SCNView()
var scnViewModule1 = SCNView()
var module1 = SCNNode?()

var connexion = NSString()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //1 - on va regarder pour copier les modules dans un dossier du dossier documents de l'appli
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var error : NSError?
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    //test dossier
    // path to documents directory
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String
    // create the custom folder path
    let myCustomDataDirectoryPath = documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/Modules.scnassets")
    // check if directory does not exist
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(myCustomDataDirectoryPath) == false {

        // create the directory
        var createDirectoryError: NSError? = nil
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(myCustomDataDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &createDirectoryError)

        // handle the error, you may call an exception
        if createDirectoryError != nil {
            println("Handle directory creation error...")
        }

    }


    //2-on teste la connexion
    let status = Reach.connectionStatus()
    switch status {
    case .Unknown, .Offline:
        println("Not connected")
        connexion = "NON"
    case .Online(.WWAN):
        println("Connected via WWAN")
        connexion = "3G"
    case .Online(.WiFi):
        println("Connected via WiFi")
        connexion = "WIFI"
    }

    //3 - on télécharge ou pas
    if ((connexion == "NON") || (connexion == "3G")){
        //on telecharge pas, on mets une alerte pour dire que les modules ne sont peut-être pas à jour
        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "MESSAGE IMPORTANT", message: "Vous n'êtes pas connecté à internet ou vous avez une connexion en 3G. Les modules ne sont peut-être pas à jour. Merci de vous connecter via un réseau wifi pour mettre à jour les modules.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        renduScene()
    }
    else if (connexion == "WIFI"){
        //on télécharge
        var URL = NSURL(string: "http://urbis-guadeloupe.fr/stoun/3Dgare/Module-01-opt.dae.zip")
        //var URL = NSURL(string: "http://urbis-guadeloupe.fr/stoun/3Dgare/B00001.png")
        Downloader.load(URL!)
        //renduScene()

        scnView3 = self.view3D as SCNView

        //on vois pour la suite - afficher la 3D
        //let scnView = self.view3D as SCNView
        scnView3.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/MASTER.dae")
        scnView3.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        scnView3.allowsCameraControl = true

        //scnViewModule1 = self.view3D as SCNView
        //test chargement dossier document
        /*if ((connexion == "NON") || (connexion == "3G")){
        var documentsDirectoryURL = filemgr.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
        documentsDirectoryURL = documentsDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/Modules.scnassets/Module-01-opt.dae")
        let module1Scene = SCNScene(URL: documentsDirectoryURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
        //println("\(module1Scene)")
        scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
        module1 = scnViewModule1.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true)
        //println("\(module1)")
        scnView3.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(module1!)
        /*let module1Scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Module-01.dae")
        scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
        module1 = scnViewModule1.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true)
        scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(module1!)*/
        }*/
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "sceneTapped:")
        scnView3.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func sceneTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view3D as SCNView

    let location = recognizer.locationInView(scnView)

    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
    if hitResults?.count > 0 {
        let result = hitResults![0] as SCNHitTestResult
        let node = result.node
        println("Node select : \(result.node.name)")
        if (result.node.name == "Module-01"){
            println("Module-01")
        }
    }
}

func telechargementOK(){

    println("Telechargement ok")
    renduScene()

}

func renduScene() {
    println("Chargement de la vue 3D")

    if let scnView2 = self.view3D as? SCNView{
        println(1)

    scnView2.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/MASTER.dae")
    scnView2.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    scnView2.allowsCameraControl = true

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var documentsDirectoryURL = filemgr.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
    documentsDirectoryURL = documentsDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/Modules.scnassets/Module-01-opt.dae")
    let module1Scene = SCNScene(URL: documentsDirectoryURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
    println("\(module1Scene)")
    scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
    module1 = scnViewModule1.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true)
    println("\(module1)")
    scnView2.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(module1!)

    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "sceneTapped:")
    scnView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }
    else {
        println(2)
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var documentsDirectoryURL = filemgr.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
        documentsDirectoryURL = documentsDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/Modules.scnassets/Module-01-opt.dae")
        let module1Scene = SCNScene(URL: documentsDirectoryURL!, options: nil, error: nil)
        println("\(module1Scene)")
        scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
        module1 = scnViewModule1.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true)
        println("\(module1)")
        scnView3.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(module1!)

    }
}

}
```

When the device is connected to internet this is the log :

```
Connected via WiFi
Success: 200
Copy from serveur successful
Remove ZIP successful
Remove dae from folder successful
Copy dae in folder successful
Remove dae from folder successful
Telechargement ok
Chargement de la vue 3D
2
Optional(<SCNScene: 0x1780e1c80>)
Optional(<SCNNode: 0x100b11a20 'Module-01' | 4 children>)
```

but SCNNode Module-01 is not on the view

when the device is offline the log :

```
Not connected
Chargement de la vue 3D
1
Optional(<SCNScene: 0x1780f7c80>)
Optional(<SCNNode: 0x13fe271b0 'Module-01' | 4 children>)
```

all is on the view
i don't understand why when the device is online the node is not on the view !

Stoun

Comment: Probably the download task is asynchronous and you're using the wrong place (and time!) to continue.

Comment: before to call telechargementOK() the file downloaded is write to documentDirectory and if it's OK i call my function.

Answer (score 0):

You use `module1!` without checking that module1 is not nil: you should check it.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lookup for the child node starting with your SCNView and other top level objects (`scnViewModule1` and `scnView2`) which don't exist until viewDidLoad(). So your search returns nil, and your force unwrapping fails. If you call your method from viewDidLoad(), the scene has been instantiated, so your calls succeed.

You don't need to go through the view just to manipulate the scene. Instead, try

```
scnViewModule1.scene = module1Scene
if let module1 = module1Scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Module-01", recursively: true) {
    module1Scene.rootNode.addChildNode(module1)
}
```